# Avoid starting a new class every time

Tags: php, oop, frameworks, autoload

I'm currently writing my own PHP Framework to get a hang of how such frameworks works. Right now I have the following structure in my project:

- project

  - application

    - config (config.php)
    - controllers (songs.php)
    - extensions (extensions of composer packages)
    - libraries (application.php, controller.php, model.php, view.php)
    - models (songsmodel.php)
    - storage (cache)
    - views (_templates, songs folder => index.php)
  - public

    - css
    - js
    - img
  - vendor (composer packages)
  - .htaccess
  - composer.json
  - index.php

So right now I'm autoloading the packages I'm using with composer's auto generated file. **How would I make it so I wouldn't have to create a new instance of package every time I wanna use it?** Right now to use one of my packages I got through composer I'm doing this - it's just an example, I would never output any "html" through my controllers:

```
/**
* Home Controller
*/

class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');

        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
..
```

I wanna do like Laravel, where you can write something like without writing "new" to init the class:

```
$user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
```

or:

```
if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Is it a "Facades" class or something like that I need to code? I'm not sure how and I couldn't find any source of knowledge.

Comment: Learn about factories and dependency injection. This lecture might give some pointers: [Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)

Comment: Laravel's facades, regardless of what anyone tells you, are static calls. As soon as you use static calls, you open up the possibility of global state *and* tie your code to the class you're pulling in - killing re-use. You will also be tied to the framework in question. Don't use statics.

Answer (score 0):

My suggest will be something like.

```
public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new thisClass();
        echo "instantiated";
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

So when you call thisClass::getInstance(); as many times as you want you will only instantiate 1 object.
Test by there will only be one instantiated message.